# "No only" or "not only"?

Tags: grammar, negation

> Care **no only** skin surface trouble, **but also** in-depth skin

Is it correct? I think "not only ~ but also" is correct.

Comment: Your sentence is incorrect and you cannot say 'no only'.

Comment: Did this sentence come from Google Translate?

Comment: You should ask your second question separately.

Answer (score 3):

It's ***incorrect!***

We generally use 'no' before a noun or a noun phrase. In almost all other structure, we use 'not'.

> Care ***not*** only skin...

An example of 'no'

> No *promise (noun)* has been made by the politician.

Read on `'not only...but also'` usage on [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/not-only-but-also).

---

However, your sentence is *awkward*.